# find an inverse function of complicated one

Tags: calculus, inverse, transcendental-equations

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$: $$f(x) = \sin (\sin (x)) +2x$$

How to calculate the inverse of this function?
So far i searched a lot in the internet but i didn't find any easy algorithm to this.
What i found is just for easy function (like $f(x)=x^2$) , but no for complicated one.

Can someone show me the steps? are they any rules i need to know?  thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Why do you want to find the inverse of this function? I'm not sure it can be done explicitly.

Comment: Are you allowed to provide a truncated Taylor series ? This is a possible (not smart !) way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two general methods exist, but often it is very hard to employ them with some success:

- integral representations as Burniston-Siewert-like representations; see: http://www4.ncsu.edu/~ces/publist.html
- series as Lagrange series: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_inversion_theorem

It is useful to remark that "simpler" equations as Kepler equation ($M=E+e\sin(E)$) needed the introduction of special functions (i.e. the Bessel functions) to be solved by means of series expansion.

For example in your case, the Lagrange inversion would give the following **formal** series solution near 0:

$$x(u)= \frac{u}{2} + \sum_{n=1} \frac{(-1)^{n}}{2(n!)}\left(\frac{d}{du}\right)^{n-1}\sin\left(\sin\left(\frac{u}{2}\right)\right)^n $$

Comment: There should be a Kepler like solution to the equation. The Fourier series coefficients would just be something like $\int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{i n t}e^{2 i n \sin(\sin(t))}dt$. Then, you would have a double sum Bessel type series solution